# Separating labelled points with a plane, minimizing label variance

Tags: optimization, statistics, clustering

Suppose we have observations with associated labels  $\{({\bf x}_1, y_1), ({\bf x}_2, y_2), \dots, ({\bf x}_n, y_n)\}$ where ${\bf x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can we efficiently find a separating plane of the observation space $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the sum of the variances of the labels of the observations within both groups is minimized?

That is, if a separating plane is parametrized by $({\bf v}, c)$ splitting the space into groups ${\bf x}_i^T {\bf v} < c$ and ${\bf x}_i^T {\bf v} \geq c$ we can formalize our search problem as:

$$\arg \min_{{\bf v}, c} {\Big (\text{var}(\{y_i : {\bf x}_i^T {\bf v} < c\}) + \text{var}(\{y_i : {\bf x}_i^T {\bf v} \geq c\})\Big)}$$
where $\text{var}(S) = \frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{t\in S}{\big(t - \frac{1}{|S|}\small\sum S\big)}^2$ is the standard definition of variance, optionally with Bessel's correction applied (either definition is fine).

---

The context  is that I had the idea of replacing the simple single-attribute decision nodes of decision trees with separating planes instead. The above method would find the greedy best split. I was wondering if doing this is even tractable?

---

Note that given $\bf v$ we can find optimal $c$ in $O(n \log n)$ time by computing all breakpoints ${\bf x}_i^T{\bf v}$, sorting, and computing the variances of each breakpoint in an online manner, choosing the best one as $c$. This gives us a randomized approximation algorithm, by repeatedly choosing a random (or better, quasi-random) unit vector $\bf v$ and finding optimal $c$. This continues for as long as desired, and the best result is returned. In theory given enough time this should return the optimal result (since a minimizing $\bf v$ is not unique and has constant probability of being chosen in any iteration), however I don't know how well it can be expected to approximate given a certain number of iterations.